# Match the reference number using left to right and len in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to match the reference number for left to right

Using SQL Server 2008

table1

Reference1

```
ABC123456
```

table2

Reference2

```
EFABC123456
ACDERERERE
ABC12345693843
```

We want to compare the reference1 with reference2 form left to right

Expected Behaviour

table2

```
Reference2

EFABC123456 - Not match
ACDERERERE - Not match
ABC12345693843 - Match (its matching the complete reference from left to right with reference1 )
```

How to make a query for the logic

Tried query

```
Left(@pi_ref, Len(table1.refno)) = table1.refno then RTRIM(LTRIM(table1.refno))
```

This query is working for complete reference number not from left to right

Please assist

Comment: wrote you an answer, but you should be aware that the performance is O(n^2). Can you tell me anything else on the data?

Answer (score 1):

```
table2.refno like table1.refno + '%'
```

Comment: @Gopal - `select case when 'ABCDE' like 'ABC' + '%' then 1 else 0 end,case when 'ABCDE' like 'BCD' + '%' then 1 else 0 end,case when 'ABCDE' like 'CDE' + '%' then 1 else 0 end
`